# SSL is required to perform this operation

Tags: json, http, ssl, https

Im retrieving some json from google, using this url - 
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=key&cx=cx&q=whatever

now this simply does not work at all, however I had a similar problem with getting json from youtube, and in that instance i changed the https to http and it worked fine. 
Now whenever I try the same solution for google, I get back the error message
SSL is required to perform this operation.

Anybody able to help? Https is obviously required, but if it isnt working then is there any way around this?

Thanks

Comment: You should really describe how you're trying to use this URL if you want some help (including saying which kind of client you're using, and perhaps a bit of code).

Answer (score 0):

> now this simply does not work at all.

Define 'doesn't work at all'. When I do it with a browser I get this:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "keyInvalid",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}
```

That's a case of 'doesn't work at all' but it is because there is something wrong with the request itself. It is not an SSL issue.

If on the other hand you do have an SSL issue you need to provide some *information.*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Just check all url you have used. You might mistakenly typed http://example.com instead the https://example.com